# Still getting Tensorflow 2.0.0 behavior after installing Tensorflow 1.15.0

Tags: tensorflow, conda

I installed Tensorflow 1.15.0 on one of the conda environment named *tensorflow1* but still `print(tf.__version__)` is printing `2.0.0`. 
Also, `tf.InterativeSession()` is not present in tensorflow 2.0. FYI, I activated the conda environment and I am working in PyCharm for my project.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Check where your pip is pointing to. 
In conda environment pip should point on 
*/userName/.conda/envs/env_name(tensorflow1 )/bin/pip* this path is local to your environment.

and inside environment don't use --user while installing packages.

Comment: my pip installation path is `C:\Users\Jastor\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow1\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.7)`. Now what should I do?

Comment: Pip is pointing to correct location. Are you using --user while installing

Comment: problem solved @MohitDuklan, I just created a new environment and installed tensorflow using cmd not using Conda Navigator.